# Unable to parse PARTITION BY in HiveQL

Tags: sql, hive, subquery, hiveql, window-functions

[image]

It seems that my version is outdated and does not support ROW_NUMBER(), PARTITION BY, and OVER(). Is there a SQL alternative to doing so?

EDIT: I'm using Hive 0.10. Windowing functions are only available in 0.11 onwards, [source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what is your doubt ? Clearly its an old hive version and thats why the query isnt working. Are you looking for a new sql to generate rownum?

Comment: @Koushik Roy yes, updated question to reflect it.

Comment: I dont know any easy way out. May be creating UDF is the only way out. You can get help from here https://blog.dataiku.com/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Hive does not support window functions, you can emulate `row_number()` with a correlated subquery:

```
select brand, name, price,
    1 + (select count(*) from products p1 where p1.brand = p.brand and p1.price > p.price) rn
from products p
```

Actually, this emulates `rank()`, not `row_number()` - unless you have duplicate prices for products of the same brand, the result is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In RDBMS SQL you can use below query :

```
WITH CTE AS  (
  SELECT 0 AS DIST 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DIST+1 FROM CTE WHERE DIST<=1000
  )
  SELECT * FROM CTE ;
```

Not sure whether it works for HQL. Try it in Hive and let me know

Comment: nope, doesnt work in hive. `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Recursive cte cte detected (cycle: cte -> cte).`